# how to select all row having separated comma value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have the following table like as below

[image]

i use the following query to fetch the record that have qulification either mca or btech or both

```
select `name` from driver_qualification 
where find_in_set('mca,btech', `qualification`) > 0
```

the qualification like dynamic $data['qualification']=mca,btech

but it return dharmendra and kapil but not jitendra

plz help me i have to search all data based on qualification.
Also i can not change the data base structure b'coz all project have dependency plz
provide the solution for that either using php and mysql

Comment: find_in_set: "This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character." [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 4):

```
select `name` from driver_qualification 
where find_in_set('mca', `qualification`) > 0 
or find_in_set('btech', `qualification`) > 0
```

Comment: i need to make dynamic query b'coz qualification like as $data['qualification']=mca,btech

Comment: try to split this value (with explode function) and iterate to generate the query above

Comment: can u provide example to iterate the query dynamically based on input parameter length

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `find_in_set()` with `in()` and it would likely be faster -

```
SELECT `name` 
FROM `driver_qualification` 
WHERE `qualifications` IN('mca','btech','mca,btech')
```

`IN()` essentially acts as a large `or` condition.

Comment: It doesn't fetch `'mca,btech'`.

Comment: It does now @notulysses, I hit enter too soon.

Comment: Ah, you didn't say where you were getting the data from @kavita. There are many solutions for that, depends on how you want to approach it.